# Regex match these words, but exclude matches with these

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a regex expression to run through several strings and match these words in them:

```
Maces Armour Evasion Shields
```

Excluding strings which contain these words alongside:

```
Swords Axes Staves
```

For example (these 2 lines are one string):

```
12% Increased Physical Damage with Maces
8% Increased Armour
```

should be a match, but this one should not be (these 2 lines are also one string but it contains forbidden word "swords" with needed word "evasion"):

```
10% Increased Evasion
8% Increased Attack Speed with Swords
```

How do I exclude that list?

Comment: why `10% Increased Evasion` is not a match?

Comment: @user3218114 These 2 lines are a full string

Comment: This application is written in C#, it's not mine, but it accepts regex expressions. I aleady tried things like (maces|armour|evasion|shields) and it was displaying matched strings, but with swords and other stuff too, thats why I want to exclude these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lookahead for needed words and a negative lookahead for forbidden words (if your regex engine allows these two features):

```
(?s)(?=.*\b(?:Maces|Armour|Evasion|Shields)\b)(?!.*\b(?:Swords|Axes|Staves)\b)^.+$
```

Comment: @Unihedron: You can't avoid the backtracking even if you put the anchor at the begining, it changes nothing.

Comment: @Unihedron: atomic groups are not needed here since the groups don't contain any quantifiers, or if you have this kind of words set: `abcd|abc|defgh|def`. However, your way works well too.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, I have no idea what regex this program accepts, but it looks like it's working somehow with your answer.. Thanks :P

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `singleline` regex:

```
/^(?=.*(?>Maces|Armour|Evasion|Shields))(?!.*(?>Swords|Axes|Staves)).+$/s
```

- `(?=.*(?>Maces|Armour|Evasion|Shields))` Asserts that one of these words are present in string **[no backtracking]**
- `(?!.*(?>Swords|Axes|Staves))` Asserts that none of these words are present in string **[no backtracking]**

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/kO7bE8/1)!